# Do we embed sailsjs into reactjs or reactsjs to sailsjs? and How can we do that?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js, web-frameworks

I am working sailsJS as web api, and reactJS as fronend. My questions is how do we embed one into anther? 
I am quite new, please point any ridiculous things that I made.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following article to see how it is done.

http://fullstackengine.net/creating-a-new-project-with-react-and-sails-js/